# How to configure table rates to exclude free shipping for some states

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I have a Magento store that sells products to all the USA states. But because of some limitations, I can provide free shipping to only some states, while people from other states have to pay for delivery.
So how can I configure table rates to allow free shipping to only particular states and limit the for other states.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a free shipping promotion via Shopping Cart Rules.

Its a little convoluted but basically the idea is that you set up the condition so that it only applies to certain states, and then if it does you offer free shipping as the promotion.  You can then select the free method under the carrier itself (e.g. UPS you could set it to be Ground).